# trouble plotting reflectance with ggplot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have a dataframe of reflectance data that I have melted to more easily use ggplot, here's the first few rows of the dataframe **bronmelt**:

```
   variety  wavelength   reflectance
1 magnolia  wavel.400    1.602868
2 carlos    wavel.450    1.778760
3 scupper   wavel.500    1.352016
4 magnolia  wavel.600    5.969302
5 scupper   wavel.900    1.491008
```

My problem is that when I call a simple plot:

```
ggplot(data=bronmelt, aes(x=wavelength, y=reflectance, color = variety)) + geom_point()
```

to plot the data, I can't get the x axis to be seen as a continuous variable.

How do I create a custom x axis from 400-900 that has tick marks every 20 points?

Comment: Can you please post a [minimal, reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610). None of the variables in your `ggplot` call are represented in your sample data. Thanks.

Comment: Edited plot call to reflect variable names

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First create a new column with numeric wavelengh values:

```
bronmelt <- transform(bronmelt, 
                      wavelength2 = as.integer(substr(wavelength, 7, 10)))
```

The plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=bronmelt, aes(x=wavelength2, y=reflectance, color = variety)) + 
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(400, 900, 20))
```

The last line specifies the axis breaks ranging from 400 to 900 in steps of 20.

[image]

Comment: +1 Good answer! I'm curious - why did you use `transform` instead of something like `bronmelt$wavelength2 <- as.integer(substr(bronmelt$wavelength, 7, 10))`? Just wondering if there are any specific advantages, or if it's just a stylistic choice. Thanks!

Comment: @MattParker It's more a stylistic choice. But the advantage is that `transform` allows to create multiple variables at once.